# Need to print class name in common code, according to situation

Tags: java

We have package like com.org.ldap.test.classname, which is shared by both DB and LDAP. As a part of log message, classname is also printed, even store is DB, log message contains ldap. We are in process of making log messages to print according to store ie for db store, should print like db.

Does any of you guys faced such issue?

Thanks in Advance,
Ashok

Comment: So something like `dbStore.getClass().getName()`?

Comment: @Tony, this will print full name including package name.

Comment: Not sure how that's a problem. But you can just substring it. `name.substring( name.lastIndexOf(".")+1 )`?

Comment: If that does what you need I can move it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is shared by both DB and LDAP, move the class out of the `ldap` package and into a `common` package. If this class contains both DB and LDAP functionality, consider splitting it into two classes, one for the DB functionality (in a db package) and the other for LDAP (in an ldap package), with a common interface.